# How Can I Manually Toggle Radio Button With a Dropdown List

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've created two radio buttons using Bootstrap, the first one just has a label and the second one has a dropdown list that contains names. If the user opens the list and selects a name, I'd like to use jquery to update the radio buttons but I can't figure out how to make it happen.  Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BigSexy/xexewf0t/) showing what I have.

Bonus points if you can show me how to reselect the first option if they uncheck all the students they may have selected!!

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label>Students to Export:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input checked="checked" name="expStudents" type="radio" previousvalue="checked"> This Student Only
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input name="expStudents" type="radio" previousvalue="false">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Multiple Students&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul id="ddStudents" class="dropdown-menu" style="width:300px; max-height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll" onclick="radioToggle();">
                <li>&nbsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent1055469" value="1055469 " onclick="ddInputsChanged('#ddStudents input', '#inpStudent0');">
                    <label for="inpStudent1055469" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 1</label>
                </li>
               <li>&nbsp;
                   <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent906219" value="906219 " onclick="ddInputsChanged('#ddStudents input', '#inpStudent0');">
                   <label for="inpStudent906219" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 2</label>
               </li>
              <li>&nbsp;
                  <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent852554" value="852554 " onclick="ddInputsChanged('#ddStudents input', '#inpStudent0');">
                 <label for="inpStudent852554" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 3</label>
              </li>
          </ul>
    </label>
</div>

function radioToggle(val) {
    $('input[name=expStudents]').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('previousValue') == 'true') {
            $(this).attr('checked', false)
        } else {
            $('input[name=expStudents]').attr('previousValue', false);
        }

        $(this).attr('previousValue', $(this).attr('checked'));
    });
}
```

Comment: wow you are giving away bonus points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added id's to your two radio buttons.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        var check = 0;
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            if(this.checked) {
                check++;
            }
        });
       if (check == 0) {
           $('#onlyStudent').prop('checked', true);
       }else if (check > 0) {
           $('#moreStudents').prop('checked', true);
       }
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label>Students to Export:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input checked="checked" id="onlyStudent" name="expStudents" type="radio" previousvalue="checked"> This Student Only
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input name="expStudents" id="moreStudents" type="radio" previousvalue="false">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Multiple Students&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="ddStudents" class="dropdown-menu" style="width:300px; max-height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll">
            <li>&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent1055469" value="1055469 ">
                <label for="inpStudent1055469" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 1</label>
            </li>
            <li>&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent906219" value="906219 ">
                <label for="inpStudent906219" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 2</label>
            </li>
            <li>&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent852554" value="852554 ">
                <label for="inpStudent852554" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

If you need simply toggle radio buttons according to existence of checkbox checked you can:

- remove the inline event handler: onclick="radioToggle();"
- add change event for checkboxes: if checked at least one checkbox toggle radio to current one, else toggle to the other one.

```js
$('#ddStudents :checkbox').on('change', function (e) {
    var currRadio = $(this).closest('.radio-inline').find('[name="expStudents"]');
    if ($('#ddStudents :checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
        currRadio.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('[name="expStudents"]').not(currRadio).prop('checked', true);
    }
});

function ddInputsChanged () {
     ;  // only for demo
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label>Students to Export:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input checked="checked" name="expStudents" type="radio" previousvalue="true"> This Student Only
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input name="expStudents" type="radio" previousvalue="false">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Multiple Students&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="ddStudents" class="dropdown-menu" style="width:300px; max-height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll">
            <li>&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent1055469" value="1055469 "
                       onclick="ddInputsChanged('#ddStudents input', '#inpStudent0');">
                <label for="inpStudent1055469" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 1</label>
            </li>
            <li>&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent906219" value="906219 "
                       onclick="ddInputsChanged('#ddStudents input', '#inpStudent0');">
                <label for="inpStudent906219" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 2</label>
            </li>
            <li>&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" class="ddStudents" id="inpStudent852554" value="852554 "
                       onclick="ddInputsChanged('#ddStudents input', '#inpStudent0');">
                <label for="inpStudent852554" class="input small dropdownLabel_NormalFont">Student 3</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </label>
</div>
```